# Could not deserialize a JMS message

Tags: java, netbeans, jboss, jms

I have a problem when I want to get my JMS message. In my logs, I have :

> 2016-02-19 09:39:54,979 INFOS [STDOUT] (Thread-0
>   (group:HornetQ-client-global-threads-29471831)) INFO  - Received
>   message:
>
> 2016-02-19 09:39:54,979 INFOS [STDOUT] (Thread-0
>   (group:HornetQ-client-global-threads-29471831)) INFO  - Message recu:
>   HornetQMessage[ID:53e7685a-d6e4-11e5-93ae-0800279925ab]:PERSISTENT
>
> 2016-02-19 09:39:54,995 INFOS [STDOUT] (Thread-0
>   (group:HornetQ-client-global-threads-29471831)) INFO  - Id de l'objet
>   à traiter: 8a80828f52f89e850152f8a9af870001
>
> 2016-02-19 09:39:54,995 INFOS [STDOUT] (Thread-0
>   (group:HornetQ-client-global-threads-29471831)) INFO  - Récupération
>   de l'objet persisité ayant pour Id: 8a80828f52f89e850152f8a9af870001
>
> 2016-02-19 09:39:54,995 INFOS [STDOUT] (Thread-0
>   (group:HornetQ-client-global-threads-29471831)) INFO  - hibernate
>   session ouverte
>
> 2016-02-19 09:39:54,995 INFOS [STDOUT] (Thread-0
>   (group:HornetQ-client-global-threads-29471831)) INFO  - Avant
>   recuperation id: 8a80828f52f89e850152f8a9af870001

I sent the iD `8a80828f52f89e850152f8a9af870001` so he can get the value (I think). But after that, I have this error :

> 2016-02-19 09:39:54,995 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener] (Thread-0
>   (group:HornetQ-client-global-threads-29471831)) Error performing load
>   command: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: **could not
>   deserialize**

But I don't know why.

I have an other question about the debug mode on netbeans. I would like to debug the part where the jms message is arrived. I know where it is in my code, but when I put a breakdown point, it doesn't work. I'm using Netbeans and JBoss.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT :**

```
     connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
     session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
     messageProducer = session.createProducer(queue);

     TextMessage oMessage = session.createTextMessage(myString);
     messageProducer.send(oMessage); //The error happens here
```

The code of the file where the ID is get is :

```
if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            TextMessage messageReceived = (TextMessage) message;
            logger.info("Message recu: " + message);
            logger.info("Id de l'objet à traiter: " + messageReceived.getText());

            idPersistSimulation = messageReceived.getText();
            // récupération de l'objet correspondant en base
            logger.info("Récupération de l'objet persisité ayant pour Id: "
                  + messageReceived.getText());

            PersistanceSimulation pSimulation = null;

            // Début Hibernate

            hSession.beginTransaction();
            logger.info("Avant recuperation id: " + messageReceived.getText());
```

**//It works until here because I can see it on the log**

```
     pSimulation = (PersistanceSimulation) hSession.get(PersistanceSimulation.class,
                  idPersistSimulation);
            // hSession.
            hSession.getTransaction().commit();
            logger.info("Nom de la simulation récupérée : " + pSimulation.getNomSimulation());
            if (!pSimulation.getEtatAvancement().equals(EtatAvancementSimulEnum.ECHEC)) {
               //lancement simulation

               pSimulation = systemeCultureSrv.lancerSimulations(pSimulation, hSession);
            }

            hSession.close();
```

The full stacktrace is really huge, I can't copy it here, I put the importanter part.

**EDIT 2 :**

> 2016-02-19 09:39:54,995 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener] (Thread-0
>   (group:HornetQ-client-global-threads-29471831)) Error performing load
>   command: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not
>   deserialize   at
>   org.hibernate.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:247)
>   [:3.6.6.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:306)
>   [:3.6.6.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:130)
>   [:3.6.6.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:116)
>   [:3.6.6.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:39)
>   [:3.6.6.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:62)
>   [:3.6.6.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64)
>   [:3.6.6.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:254)
>   [:3.6.6.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:250)
>   [:3.6.6.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:230)
>   [:3.6.6.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:331)
>   [:3.6.6.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2283)
>   [:3.6.6.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1527)
>   [:3.6.6.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1455)
>   [:3.6.6.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1355) [:3.6.6.Final]
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:611)
>   [:3.6.6.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829) [:3.6.6.Final]
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
>   [:3.6.6.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2037)
>   [:3.6.6.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:86)
>   [:3.6.6.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:76)
>   [:3.6.6.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3293)
>   [:3.6.6.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:496)
>   [:3.6.6.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:477)
>   [:3.6.6.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:227)
>   [:3.6.6.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:285)
>   [:3.6.6.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:152)
>   [:3.6.6.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1090)
>   [:3.6.6.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:1005)
>   [:3.6.6.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:998)
>   [:3.6.6.Final]    at
>   eu.akka.labs.server.mdb.JobManagerMDB.onMessage(JobManagerMDB.java:81)
>   [:]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   [:1.7.0_79]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   [:1.7.0_79]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   [:1.7.0_79]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>   [:1.7.0_79]   at
>   org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeTarget(MethodInvocation.java:122)
>   [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.2.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:111)
>   [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.2.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.container.ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.invokeNext(ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.java:72)
>   [:1.1.3]  at
>   org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.invoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:76)
>   [:1.1.3]  at
>   org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.aroundInvoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:62)
>   [:1.1.3]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) [:1.7.0_79]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   [:1.7.0_79]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   [:1.7.0_79]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>   [:1.7.0_79]   at
>   org.jboss.aop.advice.PerJoinpointAdvice.invoke(PerJoinpointAdvice.java:174)
>   [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.2.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>   [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.2.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.fillMethod(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:74)
>   [:1.1.3]  at
>   org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_29548404.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_29548404.java) [:]   at
>   org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>   [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.2.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.setup(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:90)
>   [:1.1.3]  at
>   org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_29548404.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_29548404.java)
>   [:]   at
>   org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>   [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.2.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.ejb3.async.impl.interceptor.AsynchronousServerInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousServerInterceptor.java:110)
>   [:1.7.21]     at
>   org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>   [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.2.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.ejb3.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:62)
>   [:1.7.21]     at
>   org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>   [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.2.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:56)
>   [:1.7.21]     at
>   org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>   [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.2.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47)
>   [:1.7.21]     at
>   org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>   [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.2.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
>   [:1.0.4]  at
>   org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>   [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.2.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:68)
>   [:1.7.21]     at
>   org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>   [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.2.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.ejb3.core.context.InvocationContextAdapter.proceed(InvocationContextAdapter.java:70)
>   [:1.7.21]     at
>   org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:223)
>   [:0.0.2]  at
>   org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:353)
>   [:0.0.2]  at
>   org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.invoke(CMTTxInterceptor.java:209)
>   [:0.0.2]  at
>   org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.aop.CMTTxInterceptorWrapper.invoke(CMTTxInterceptorWrapper.java:52)
>   [:0.0.2]  at
>   org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>   [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.2.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
>   [:1.0.4]  at
>   org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>   [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.2.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.java:79)
>   [:1.7.21]     at
>   org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>   [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.2.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.ejb3.BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.invoke(BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.java:67)
>   [:1.7.21]     at
>   org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>   [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.2.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.ejb3.core.context.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:47)
>   [:1.7.21]     at
>   org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>   [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.2.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.aspects.currentinvocation.CurrentInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationInterceptor.java:67)
>   [:1.0.1]  at
>   org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>   [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.2.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.EJB3TCCLInterceptor.invoke(EJB3TCCLInterceptor.java:86)
>   [:1.7.21]     at
>   org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>   [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.2.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.MessagingContainer.localInvoke(MessagingContainer.java:306)
>   [:1.7.21]     at
>   org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.inflow.MessageInflowLocalProxy.delivery(MessageInflowLocalProxy.java:299)
>   [:1.7.21]     at
>   org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.inflow.MessageInflowLocalProxy.invoke(MessageInflowLocalProxy.java:152)
>   [:1.7.21]     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.onMessage(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.hornetq.ra.inflow.HornetQMessageHandler.onMessage(HornetQMessageHandler.java:278)
>   [:6.1.0.Final]    at
>   org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.callOnMessage(ClientConsumerImpl.java:866)
>   [:6.1.0.Final]    at
>   org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.access$100(ClientConsumerImpl.java:44)
>   [:6.1.0.Final]    at
>   org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl$Runner.run(ClientConsumerImpl.java:983)
>   [:6.1.0.Final]    at
>   org.hornetq.utils.OrderedExecutorFactory$OrderedExecutor$1.run(OrderedExecutorFactory.java:100)
>   [:6.1.0.Final]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   [:1.7.0_79]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   [:1.7.0_79]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [:1.7.0_79]
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   fr.inra.grignon.persyst.common.bo.PersistanceSimulation$EtatAvancementSimulEnum
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) [:1.7.0_79]
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) [:1.7.0_79]
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   [:1.7.0_79]   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) [:1.7.0_79]
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) [:1.7.0_79]
>     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>   [:1.7.0_79]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>   [:1.7.0_79]   at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [:1.7.0_79]
>     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274) [:1.7.0_79]  at
>   org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:304)
>   [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1172)
>   [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:886)
>   [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.doLoadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:505)
>   [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:450)
>   [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) [:1.7.0_79]     at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [:1.7.0_79]   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274) [:1.7.0_79]   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:625)
>   [:1.7.0_79]   at
>   org.hibernate.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.resolveClass(SerializationHelper.java:368)
>   [:3.6.6.Final]    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1612)
>   [:1.7.0_79]   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
>   [:1.7.0_79]   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readEnum(ObjectInputStream.java:1725)
>   [:1.7.0_79]   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
>   [:1.7.0_79]   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
>   [:1.7.0_79]   at
>   org.hibernate.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:244)
>   [:3.6.6.Final]    ... 93 more

Comment: A little bit of code and the complete stacktrace would be helpful...

Comment: @Frank I edited the post with some code.

Comment: @Frank I created a pastebin to see the full logs : http://pastebin.com/Za8XUXk9

Comment: Unfortunately the company firewall is blocking pastebin :-( But from what I see I would guess that either PersistanceSimulation  or any of it's members do not implement Serializable. Have you checked that?

Comment: @Frank In fact, the code is not mine and it already works. I'm just trying to deploy it on my computer. So the code should work, it's probably a config problem :/

Comment: @Frank And I added more of the stacktrace but not the entire :/

Comment: @Frank I checked but it implements Serializable

Comment: If it's already working code than it is different. Do you use the same database as in the working installation? Do you have the same datatypes/hibernate mappings? Same Java-Version? Can you post the PersistanceSimulation code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103940/discussion-between-erlaunis-and-frank).

Comment: Sorry, chat is also blocked by company firewall. :-(

Comment: @Frank What a restrictive compagny ^^ Ok, so I'm using Java 7 instead of Java 6.The database is the same. The mappings are the same (I think). The PersistanceSimulation is just a class with attributes which extends BO. BO is also a class with attributes and it implements Serializable and Comparable.

Comment: Looking a little bit closer at your stacktrace I found 
     `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fr.inra.grignon.persyst.common.bo.PersistanceSimulation$EtatAvancementSimulEnum` Can you verify that class is really there and loaded by the classloader?

Comment: @Frank EtatAvancementSimulEnum is an attribut of the class PersistanceSimulation. That's why I don't understand this error, because he's pointing an attribut instead of a class. But how can I check if the class is leaded by the classloader ?

Comment: The classes loaded can be logged by extending the jboss-log4j.xml with `<category name="org.jboss.classloader">
   <priority value="DEBUG"/>
</category>` Two more ideas: What type is the attribute EtatAvancementSimulEnum? And does any of the members or PersistanceSimulation have a field of type Vector? The serialization of Vector changed from Java 6 to Java 7...

Comment: The attribut is an Enum of strings. And in the PersistanceSimulation and in BO classes, there is no Vecor. But I know that somewhere else, it exists some fields of type Vector. Should I change my Java version ?

Comment: It could be a try to downgrade, though Java 6 is EOL. Otherwise you could replace all occurences of Vector with ArrayList.

Comment: I'm downloading the Java 6. But the Vector are from a framework, so I can't change it.

Comment: @Frank It broke everything, I can't access to the app anymore ...

Comment: Then you should rollback to java7 and look for the missing EtatAvancementSimulEnum.